# N64 Ghidra setup: missing MIPS instructions?

Tags: ghidra, mips

I have been using Ghidra, along with VoidWarranty's N64 loader to figure out analyze some unused functionality in an obscure title. however, it does  not recognize valid instructions with the default selected MIPS CPU, such as `0xdf410328` (`LD AT,0x0328(K0)`), `0xff410328` (`SD AT,0x0328(K0)`), `0xfcb00098` (`SD S0,0x0098(A1)`). is this an issue with ghidra's definition, or am i just using the wrong processor for the job (MIPS:BE:32:default (1.5))?

Comment: Would probably helpful to state exactly which Ghidra processor you're using as MIPS64 has the SD and LD implemented.  You should probably also give an example full 4 byte instruction and not just 1 1/2 bytes

Comment: Full instructions and cpu added.

Comment: Yeah looks like you choose (or your loader, not familiar with it) 32 bit, but should be 64 bit

Comment: If that's the case, does anyone know which setting matches the r4300i?

Comment: at this point you should probably file an issue on the github page for the voidwarranty loader to see why your rom is different.  Best guess though is probably MIPS:BE:64:64-32addr

Comment: Found a similar issue that was closed, with the loader developer saying "just try a different one." The suggested cpu config gave even more "unrecognized operation" errors when analyzing the rom.